# Shannon's entropy negative indicator

Tags: entropy, weighted-data, weights

I have a composite indicators whose indicators I want to weight, for which I am calculating the Shannon's entropy. Problem is some indicators measure growth and thus can be negative. Standardizing respective to the min or the max, doesn't eliminate negative values, but the equation includes a logarithm of the standardized values, and that can be calculated.
Any hint? I thought about using min max standardization (0-1) instead of proximity to the max, but not sure if that is an option or will affect the quality of the tool.

Hope I explained myself properly.

---

Ok, 
For example in this excel shot, each row are the values for a given city for each one of those indicators. Indicators I want to weight their importance using Shannon's entropy. There are hundreds of cities and no value is going to be repeated.

[image: values example]

Comment: I can't see that entropy (at least as interpreted in the one answer at the time of writing) is at all helpful or even pertinent for such measures: they are continuous measures.

Answer (score 0):

Negative values do not affect the computation of H (Shannon's entropy).

To compute H you must use the probabilities of observing each value for each of you variables (measurements, indicators).

Example:

Imagine you have some variable X which takes the following values:

{1,2,-2,-2,5,-3,0,1,-2,9}

First compute the probability of observing each value:

p(X=1) = $\frac{2}{10}$

p(X=2) = $\frac{1}{10}$

p(X=-2) = $\frac{3}{10}$

p(X=5) = $\frac{1}{10}$

p(X=-3) = $\frac{1}{10}$

p(X=0) = $\frac{1}{10}$

p(X=9) = $\frac{1}{10}$

Then you plug those probabilities in the formula for H

$H=-\sum_{i=1}^n p(X=x_i)log(\frac{1}{p(X=x_i)})$

Comment: Ok, I am confused. I have followed the procedure from a couple of papers and they don't do it like that, basically because no value is repeated. I dont know how to write equatins in the web, to share the equations.

Comment: First you have to recognize which are your variables. I am assuming "indicators" are what you are measuring. Your indicators can take several values. It is the probabilities of those values you have to compute first. Then you can compute the entropy of each indicator. If you can add a table representing your data, that would be very helpful.

Comment: There is the picture. Problem I have is one of the indicators represent growth, and its value is negative for some cities, so I cant calculate its Ln, even if I normalize from 0 to 1, there will always be a  0 value, not being to calculate Ln either way.

Comment: Recipe is incorrect. You can write $\sum p \ln(1/p)$ or $-\sum p \ln p$ but what you give is a mishmash of the two. Further the example is misleading at the level needed: you can calculate entropy like this for integer inputs, but you are ignoring their exact values and even their order, so entropy is not usually interesting or useful for such data. The recipe here makes most sense for discrete categories such as frog, toad, newt with given empirical probabilities of occurrence.